# How do I make a 2D race car turn smoothly?

Tags: 2d, rotation, movement, vector, car

I'm making a competitive 2-player 2D racing game for a school project. I'm struggling with the movements of my car: I made it a square for testing purposes and it can move left, right, up or down, but it can't make *smooth turns around corners*.

How can I make my car (currently a square) make smooth movements? I've heard vectors might help, but I don't know how to use them.

I'm writing this in C# with Visual Studio.

---

My car control code looks like this right now:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs key) {
    // player1 controls
    if (key.KeyCode == Keys.Up)     { Player1.Top -= 5; }
    if (key.KeyCode == Keys.Down)   { Player1.Top += 5; }

    if (key.KeyCode == Keys.Left)   { Player1.Left -= 5; }
    if (key.KeyCode == Keys.Right)  { Player1.Left += 5; }

    // player2 controls
    if (key.KeyCode == Keys.W) { Player2.Top -= 5; }
    if (key.KeyCode == Keys.S) { Player2.Top += 5; }

    if (key.KeyCode == Keys.A) { Player2.Left -= 5; }
    if (key.KeyCode == Keys.D) { Player2.Left += 5; }
}
```

Comment: You need to rotate the car while it's moving and then move it in the direction it facing. The keys should affect velocity and not movements directly in the sense that keys control acceleration.

Comment: We heared that, only the code of that is so hard to figure out :s

Comment: @elipoo X = speed * cos( rotation ), Y = speed * sin( rotation ). It's that easy.

Comment: [This question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26845/i-am-looking-to-create-realistic-car-movement-using-vectors?rq=1) has some good information, specifically in [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/33594/30431).

Comment: @Ben still figuring out how..

Comment: @XGundam05 it has to be written in c# so that code won't help me.

Comment: Definitely ask your teacher too, or a math teacher at your school. When I was learning vectors and trigonometry, it really helped to have someone around who could draw pictures of them and talk through what they were doing. Your teachers also know you better than we do, so they can tune their explanation to your current understanding. (There are also great Khan Acedemy courses [on vectors](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors_and_spaces) and [trig](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry)!)

Comment: @elipoo the logic is still the same, and the answer to that question is done in pseudocode.

Comment: @Anko We got 5 weeks of lessons and this is our first project. We asked him for 2 times but he still says that we have to search more. But every comment is helping :).

Answer (score 5):

Start by adding a variable for the angle that the car is moving at.

```
float angle = Math.Pi / 2;
```

Then add a variable for the current speed.

```
float speed = 0.0;
```

Now create three constants:

public static final float acceleration = 0.1;
public static final float maxSpeed = 5.0;
public static final float rotationRate = Math.Pi / 50;

For starters, get your controls *somewhat* right:

Do this every frame:

```
private void everyTick()
{
    player.top -= Math.sin(Player1.angle) * Player1.speed;
    player.left += Math.cos(Player1.angle) * Player1.speed;
}
```

Do this on key press:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs key)
{
    //player1 controls
    if (key.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        Player1.speed += accelaration;
        Player1.speed = Math.min(Player1.speed,maxSpeed);
    }
    if (key.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
    {
        Player1.speed -= accelaration;
        Player1.speed = Math.max(Player1.speed, -maxSpeed);
    }
    if (key.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
    {
        Player1.angle += rotationRate;
    }
    if (key.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
        Player1.angle -= rotationRate;
    }

}
```

This should get you started.

Comment: private void Player(string[] args )
        {
            double angle = Math.Pi / 2;
            double speed = 0.0;
           
        }

        
            public void final(float[ ]args) 
           
            {
                const double acceleration = 0.1;
           
            }
         public void final(float[ ]args) 
           
            {
                const double maxSpeed = 5.0;
           
            }
        public void final(float[ ]args) 
           
            {
                double rotationRate = Math.Pi / 50;
           
            }

Comment: this is youre 2 first steps, dont know if i'm doing it right but it gives a lot of errors right now.

Answer (score 1):

First use Zehelvion answer to make the car turn correctly, then:

Use the timestamp, you measure how much time it took for your last iteration and use that to modulate the speed at which you are changing things.

```
void RunGame(float deltatime)
{
    if (key.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        Player1.speed += accelaration * deltatime
        Player1.speed = Math.min(Player1.speed,maxSpeed)
...
```

This will make it much smoother even if the framerate goes up or down (why accelerate twice as fast if the framerate goes from 30 to 60 in some area?).

Comment: i'm still trying to use the code of Zehelvion only the variable and constant part isnt really working so have to fix that. After that i will try this :).